# StaggeredGridLayoutManager make auto_fit columns

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

How i can make StaggeredGridLayoutManager auto_fit with all screens size , set number of columns automatically

```
recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
```

Comment: Which thridparty StaggeredGridlayout r u using

Comment: sorry i'm new in android and i get this code from tutorial what you mean "thridparty" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(getSpan(), StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

```
public int getSpan() {
    int orientation = getScreenOrientation(getActivity());
    if (isTV(getActivity())) return 4;
    if (isTablet(getActivity()))
        return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? 2 : 3;
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? 2 : 3;
}


public static boolean isTV(Context context) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2 && ((UiModeManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE))
            .getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION;
}

public static int getScreenOrientation(Context context) {
    return context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels <
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels ?
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT : Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
}

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

Comment: this make 2 card in normal and 3 in landscape view i don't want that i want to set it automatically depends on size of screen

Comment: okay. If you found any solution let me know. So that i can use it for future

Answer (score 0):

If your items are at the same width, you can do this:

```
mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGLobalLayoutListener(this);
                int viewWidth = mRecyclerView.getMeasuredWidth();
                float cardViewWidth = getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_layout_width);
                int newSpanCount = (int) Math.floor(viewWidth / cardViewWidth);
                mLayoutManager.setSpanCount(newSpanCount);
                mLayoutManager.requestLayout();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create help class for getting sizes.

```
public class GetSize {
    public static int getColumnCount(Context context, int dp) {
        if ((double) (getScreenWidth(context)/getPointOfDp(context, dp)) <= 1) return 1;
        else return getScreenWidth(context)/getPointOfDp(context, dp);
    }

    public static int getScreenWidth(Context context){

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);

        return point.x; //Screen width
    }

    private static int getPointOfDp(Context context, int dp) { //Convert from dp to screen dots
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

For get a column count need set some minimal width of your item.

```
int columnCount = GetSize.getColumnCount(context, 288);

layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```